# Вечно спорная запятая после "ну": междометие или частица?

Tags: пунктуация, частица, междометие

> И, обращаясь к кому-то про себя, всё это время просила: «**Ну
>   пожалуйста!** Мне всё очень нравится, но можно всё-таки начинать жить
>   в какое-то другое время?»

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это ***частица*** здесь. Произносится без паузы, с ударением на *"пожалуйста".* Если бы это было междометие, то интонационно бы выделялись оба слова и была бы пауза.